# Integration from mobile app with passbook to direct user to add credit card to Apple Pay

Tags: ios, passbook, applepay

Is there a way to re-direct a user from your iOS mobile app to Passbook to enter their credit card into Apple Pay?

For example, can a mobile banking or credit card application from a credit issuer -create a button to direct a user to add credit card to Apple Pay?  I would presume this would require launching of Passbook to the appropriate place to add a credit card in Passbook.  I think the physical card is still required.

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect whether a user has a card or not (at least, there's no documented way; credit card issuers might have access to a special API). The user doesn't physically need the card to add it.

You can open the Passbook app like so:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"shoebox://"]];
```

However, this isn't documented, and might break in future versions of iOS, just like the Settings URL scheme broke in iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible since iOS 8.3

```
+(void) openApplePaySetup
{
     if([PKPassLibrary isPassLibraryAvailable])
     {
          PKPassLibrary* library = [[PKPassLibrary alloc] init];
          [library openPaymentSetup];
     }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 0):

Swift version

```
if PKPassLibrary.isPassLibraryAvailable() {
   let library = PKPassLibrary()
   library.openPaymentSetup()
}
```